# Retrieve texte from a Masters

Tags: vba, csv, visio

I'm working on Visio 2013 for a project and I'm new to VBA and Visio.

First, I wrote a function which imports a CSV file in the current visio document by creating first a string table `texte` of the CSV and then adding it in a shape:

```
Dim sp As Visio.Shape
Set sp = ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Drop(Visio.ActiveDocument.Masters("Puce 120"), 4, 10)
sp.Characters.Text = texte
```

Now I want to write the reverse function, from the shape to a CSV file but I can't find a way to access the text in my shape "Puce 120".

I wrote this:

```
Dim vsoMasters As Visio.Masters
Dim intMasterCount As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim vsoMaster As Visio.Master

Set vsoMasters = ActiveDocument.Masters    
intMasterCount = vsoMasters.Count

If intMasterCount > 0 Then
    For intCounter = 1 To intMasterCount
        If vsoMasters.Item(intCounter).Name = "Puce 120" Then
            Set vsoMaster = vsoMasters.Item(intCounter)
        End If
    Next intCounter
Else
    Debug.Print " No masters in document"
End If

Dim shap As Visio.Shapes
Set shap = vsoMaster.Shapes

Dim ch As Visio.Characters
ch = shap.Characters
```

But I don't find my text in `ch`. Can someone explain me how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put and get text of a shape using `shape.Text` property.
Is there any reason for all other fancy stuff? That is, you can set shape text like this:

```
shape.Text = "Hello"
```

And get it back like this:

```
myText = shape.Text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have to put my text in a "Puce 120" Master because it's an instruction I have. My problem is to retrieve it from this Master in fact. The second function I write is independent from the first so I have to find my Master Puce 120 first in the page and then retrieve the text. But I don't find it when I search in the properties of the Master. I find a Property "Shapes" but I don't find the text thaht I wrote inside de Master, juste "Text = Puce 120"

Comment: You don't find it because it does not exist in the master; you put your text in the shape (not in the master) with your first code snippet. What do you actually want to do (i.e. basic idea?) "Shape" in Visio relates to a "Master" as "Object" (Instance) relates to a "Class" (Type) in a programming language.

Comment: The idea is that the first function will import a csv file in a Puce 120 shape and the second function will do the reverse thing. From the Puce 120 shape retrieve the text and write it in a csv file. But the 2 functions are not done successively, so I can't pass the shape in parameter. I've done it in word but I have trouble with visio

Comment: Then it seems you don't need any masters. Just use the code like above with "shape.Text"... why masters?! Maybe you mean, you want to find the shape which you dropped at step 1?

Comment: In case you need to find a shape, you can just mark it at step 1 (add a data field to it to mark it). Or remember it's ID. Or it's name (or give it a specific name so that you can find it later by that name). Or iterate over all shapes, and check which shapes were created out of master named "Puce 120" by examining shape's Master property.

Comment: Actually I didn't write that code with the Master. A collegue wrote it so I rely on this to write the reverse function . And yes, I want to find the shape I dropped that's why I am searching throught the masters to find my Puce 120.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94852/discussion-between-user3314570-and-nikolay).